# loop through visible cells after filtering

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

```
For Each cell In rnData.Columns(13).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If cell > 0.25 And cell < 0.3 And cell.Offset(0, 3) >= valueMin And cell.Offset(0, 3) < valueMax And Year(cell.Offset(0, -2)) = Year(Sheet3.Cells(4, 3)) And Month(cell.Offset(0, -2)) = Month(Sheet3.Cells(4, 3)) Then
        sum1 = sum1 + cell.Offset(0, 7)
    End If
Next
```

This code returns an run-time error 13, what could be the problem?

Comment: Could be a number of things - error values in the cells, or cells not containing the data type (dates/numbers) required for the operations you are attempting.

Answer (score 0):

Error number 13 could be achieved if you are trying to add string to a number.
Thus in `sum1 = sum1 + cell.Offset(0, 7)` `cell.Offset(0,7)` is probably a string.

Rewrite your code like this:

```
For Each cell In rnData.Columns(13).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If cell > 0.25 And cell < 0.3 And cell.Offset(0, 3) >= valueMin And cell.Offset(0, 3) < valueMax And Year(cell.Offset(0, -2)) = Year(Sheet3.Cells(4, 3)) And Month(cell.Offset(0, -2)) = Month(Sheet3.Cells(4, 3)) Then
        debug.print cell.Offset(0,7);sum
        sum1 = sum1 + cell.Offset(0, 7)
    End If
Next
```

When the runtime error shows up, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and take a look at the values at the immediate window. One of them should be a string, not a number.

Comment: i think it is counting the header row, which is a string not a number, how can I fix it?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it by setting the filter range from .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("T2").End(xlDown)) to .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("T2").End(xlDown))